# How to Start activity in a new window Using WebView?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-viewpager, android-webview

I have a ViewPager with several fragments inside, and one of them contains a webview. Inside that WebView, I would like to open links to images (jpeg/png) in a designated activity which I use to show images:

**MyFragment.java**

```
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

        public void startImageView(String url) {
            Intent imageIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), ImageActivity.class);
            imageIntent.putExtra(ImageActivity.IMAGE_URL, Uri.parse(url));
            startActivity(imageIntent);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url){
            if (url.toLowerCase().endsWith(".png") || url.toLowerCase().endsWith(".jpg") || url.toLowerCase().endsWith(".jpeg")) {
                startImageView(url);
            } else {
                view.loadUrl(url);
            }
            return false;
       }

    });
```

**ImageActivity.java**

```
public class ImageActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_image_full_size);
...
}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
...
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.main.ImageActivity"
            android:label="Picture"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        >
        </activity>
...
```

When I click on an image link inside the webview, the image activity indeed loads. However, the activity is loaded **inside** the fragment, instead of opening in a new window (as activities usually do). When I start this activity from a different activity (and not inside a webview as mentioned above) the activity opens in a new window as expected. Any ideas how to open the ImageActivity in a new window when started from WebView?

Comment: I like your question.

Comment: how can ImageActivity.class has class name as FullImageActivity?

Comment: @AnirudhSharma - sorry, you're right. I changed it for clarity in this post, and forgot to rename all occurrences. Fixed it.

Comment: Did you try `getActivity().getApplicationContext()` without `getActivity()` in `startImageView`?

Comment: @Wishmaster - yes, unfortunately it did not work.

Comment: @Ohad can you explain what is mean "new window"? I've made sample like yours and `ImageActivity` opens standard.

Comment: Try with JavaScript interface

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29779954/android-webview-showtoast-onbuttonclick/29780068#29780068

Comment: @Wishmaster The activity is opened inside the fragment. That is, the ViewPager is still visible, and the activity shows up inside of the current fragment. I would like the activity to open in a new window on top of the View Pager.

Comment: Are you sure that the activity is opening inside the fragment? I believe its the web view rendering the image. Add some logcat and see that it passes the condition and actually executes startImageView() method. Also return appropriately from shouldUrlLoading() method.

Answer (score 0):

What you're saying is impossible on Android. `startActivity` would never render an Activity "inside of a fragment". Therefore once you eliminate the impossible, whatever remains, no matter how improbable, must be the truth.

```
if (url.toLowerCase().endsWith(".png") || url.toLowerCase().endsWith(".jpg") || url.toLowerCase().endsWith(".jpeg")) {
                startImageView(url);
            } else {
                view.loadUrl(url);
            }
```

Your if statement is most likely going into the ELSE part and so the WebView is loading the image.

Do you have an example of a url for the images you load - perhaps add logs to this if else statement.

Do your images have query paramaters on them? i.e. is the url actually `www.foo.com/bar/image.png?w=300h=300`? Therefore `endsWith` will not work.  Try changing to this: `url.toLowerCase().contains(".png")`

i.e.

```
String candidateUrl = url.toLowerCase();
if (candidateUrl.contains(".png") 
   || candidateUrl.contains(".jpg") 
   || candidateUrl.contains(".jpeg")) {
   Log.d("MyTag", "Start a new activity for: " + url);
   startImageView(url);
} else {
   Log.d("MyTag", "Load inside webview " + url);
   view.loadUrl(url);
}
```